# Array dont take all the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem when I integrate my jQuery script on my application, it doesn't work at all.
It can't take this data (class name):

```
orderArray.push($("li")[i].className.slice(5));
```

Anyone knows why this line of the script doesn't work?
I have tried to change data type to this:

```
orderArray.push($(el).text());
```

And it works, but I need the other data to process the form.
The UL and they LI are generated by a PHP script that is included and in other folder.

HTML output:

```
<ul id="opciones" class="order_list ui-sortable">
<li class="item_1">Critero</li>
<li class="item_2">No criterio</li>
<li class="item_3">Quizas criterio</li>
</ul>
```

When i serialize it and use the two argument to take data and put it on value of input this is the result:

```
["Critero","","No criterio","","Quizas criterio",""]
```

The second data `(orderArray.push($("li")[i].className.slice(5));)` is always in blank

What I expect:

```
["Critero","1","No criterio","2","Quizas criterio","3"]
```

Comment: Could you post the output you're getting, what you except and the HTML of your `li`'s?

Comment: Probably because either `$("li")[i]` or `$("li")[i].className` doesn't always exist.

Comment: Thanks for your time, i have updated my question whit the data you have request.

Comment: Whats the sense of `className.slice(5))`? `className` returns string and `slice` function is used for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for:

```
var orderArray = [];

$('#opciones li').each(function(i, li) {
    orderArray.push($(li).text(), ++i);
});

alert(orderArray);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3gqX/)